# Make Tree output wider?

Tags: trees, magnification

I use Tree and what I have in the nodes is somewhat larger output (horizontally). That means the nodes are displayed with a lot of overlap. Is there a way to make the "outgoing" edges to the child nodes go farther away, so that the child nodes are stretched a bit farther apart.

I have tried various settings, but I don't want to change the embedding. The only remedy I found was ImageSize->400, but now the whole tree is a bit too big. So I shrunk it with Magnify[..., 8/10], that now looks somewhat ok, but still leaves the outgoing edges too long.

Ideal would be a way to specify that the outgoing edges should have a larger angle between them. It would allow me to prevent this getting too tall as the edges are too long.

Update a few hours later:
Someone sent me in a private note that I should try using RootVertex, and finally I found

TreeLayout->{"LayeredEmbedding","LeafDistance"->2,RootVertex->1}

does what I want.

Comment: Please provide an example, a screenshot, and the version you are using. ``Tree`` is still marked as experimental, and there are some differences betwen the latest versions.

Comment: You can also adjust the AspectRatio

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it to work so nicely as with the solution I posted.